# Jenkins and GitLab integration URL issue

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to use the integration between GitLab and Jenkins.
My issue is all my projects in Jenkins are in this format:

```
http://IP:8080/job/JOBNAME/
```

but in GitLab it is hardcoded `.../project/...`.

So, every time I try to push something I can't connect and I receive a 404.
I don't know either how to change URI in Jenkins or in GitLab.

[image: GitLab config IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

In your GitLab server's web UI open your project/repo → *Settings* → *Webhooks* → *URL*: `...there should be your Jenkins URL....`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for webhook then you have to configure it under your respository. `Settings` -> `webhooks` and there you have add your

Jenkins job url in this format

`https://<YOUR JENKINS URL/project/YOUR JOB NAME`

and don't forget to copy the token from jenkins job and add it to section here in gitlab secret token field.